# Strange class behaviour; Gets applied to drop list option when it shouldn't

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, forms

This is kindof hard to explain...

I have this class:

```
.nav_option_main {
    background-color: #FC9;
}
```

I have two drop-lists, let's call them Drp1 and Drp2.
Drp2 is populated depending on Drp1:s value, using javascript.

Some values in Drp2 has the above class applied to them, but only some.

Now, here is the strange problem, lets say I have made a selection on Drp1, and the Drp2 is filled with options (using js). Then, if option number 5 in Drp2 has the class applied to it so the background changes, and I change Drp1 to something else, then Drp2:s option number 5 hasn't changed the bgr color (because the class seem to have been cached somehow, and applied to it).

Another example:

I choose `fruits` from `Drp1`. `Drp2` is populated with lets say 3 `fruits`, `banana`, `apple`, and `lemon`. Lets say `Lemon` has the `class` applied to it, so `lemon has a background color`!
Then if I choose for example `countries` in `Drp1`, and `Drp2` is filled with `5 countries`, the third country's background color is still not changed even though the class isn't applied to it, why? So the countries could be `US`, `Canada`, `France`, `Russia`, 
`China`, in that order. Then France would have the background color attached to it, even though in the code it shouldn't have!

If you need more info just let me know and I will come up with some more examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the js that changes drp2 according to drp1, are you removing the option element and recreating it, or are you just changing the value? The former should work; the latter will result in keeping the class, as you're not changing the element

Comment: To build on this answer, it would be in your best interest to iterate through each item in Drp2 and set `className` to `""` in order to clear all the classes.

Comment: Not if you're removing all the elements anyway